# VueJS pass object to array in prop

Tags: arrays, vue.js, prop

```
 <gmap-map :center="center" :zoom="19" style="width: 100%; height: 750px" map-type-id="hybrid">
    <gmap-info-window :options="infoOptions" :position="infoWindowPos" :opened="infoWinOpen" @closeclick="infoWinOpen=false">
        {{infoContent}}
    </gmap-info-window>
    <template v-for="pin in pins">
        lat: {{pin.latitude}},lng: {{pin.longitude}}
        <gmap-marker :icon="{url: themepath + 'pin.png'}" :position="{lat: pin.latitude, lng: pin.longitude}" :clickable="true" @click="toggleInfoWindow(m,i)"></gmap-marker>
    </template>
</gmap-map>
```

I have this code above and I am trying to pass `:position="{lat: pin.latitude, lng: pin.longitude}"` using the `v-for` loop contents but this doesn't seem to be working. Is there an easier way to pass these?

Comment: What is happening when you do this? Do you get errors, unexpected results, what? I see nothing inherently wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: Are you declaring `position` as a prop in your `gmap-marker` component

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. What does your `pins` data look like?